# Where to start to work as a back-end developer?

Tags: web, backend

I tell you my current situation, since I am somewhat lost right now:

I have been working as a full-stack developer for the last 4 years, using PHP and Prestashop as main technologies and Laravel in certain projects. For the front part I have worked with Javascript, React and Bootstrap. In August I decided to leave my full-stack job, since I wasn't happy with the conditions. After leaving this job, I started looking for a new job where I could learn new technologies and leave Prestashop behind. My goal was to focus on back-end development with PHP, either with Laravel or Symfony. As I started applying to different companies, I realized how much lack of knowledge in technologies and practices I have. I list some of the following things that I had never used in my previous jobs and that I regularly see in job offers:

- AWS
- IC/DC
  -CleanCode
- DDD
  -Docker
  -elasticsearch
  -Jenkins
- Kubernetes
- SOLID
- TDD

Having been working in rather small companies, I have not been able to learn all this knowledge, since it was not necessary to carry out my work or was not a priority. Now I realize many of the things I need to get the kind of job I would like, but the following question arises: how could I get all this knowledge? I could take courses on each of these technologies, but would they help me get a job or would they require me to have used them previously in other jobs? I have many doubts about where to start to get a better job than the one I had and where best practices are applied when developing and I am afraid that I will have to go back to some Prestashop company like the previous ones I have been in, since I could not enter companies that require this knowledge because I have no experience with them.

Where would it be advisable to start in my case? Would you look for a job similar to the ones I've had before to continue earning money while studying or would you go directly for a job where you can learn these technologies?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Exact. The conditions in my previous job were really bad and I did not want to continue my work in that company any longer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, I keep that in mind for future interviews. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "My previous company was using outdated technologies and provided no opportunity for advancement, so I decided to bet on myself and take some time to learn new technologies [x y z]." Easy enough, though of course still not ideal.  As far as learning new technologies on the job, do you tend to learn quickly on the job? Have you examples ready to provide to show you do?

Comment: @Joe Yes, I tend to learn new technologies relatively quickly, because I don't mind practicing after the workday is over. As you mentioned, I have some Github repositories ready to show companies, the problem is that I am currenlty learning the knowledge that companies ask for and it will take me some time to catch up with everything. The main advantage of having left my job is that, as you mentioned, I can focus on learning and updating myself, something that I could not have combined with my previous job. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where would it be advisable to start in my case?

Search for positions that ask for a combination of technologies that you already know and technologies that you want to learn.  This way, you can use your existing knowledge and experience to be able to be hired and then you can hopefully transition to the technologies that you are interested in while on the job.

It looks a lot better to potential employers to see a resume/CV with actual work experience in ( some ) technologies that they use as opposed to only courses/github/certifications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!